# How to change a buffer string to uppercase within a program?

Tags: c

I have a problem in C program. I have already a string in buffer and want to change the string to upper case and then write to the socket or take it to standard out.Please help me in below code.

```
char input[] = buffer;
int  alpha_count = 0;
for (int i = 0, x = strlen(input); i < x; i++) {
  if (isalpha(input[i])) {
    if (alpha_count++ % 2 == 0 ) 
      input [i] = toupper(input[i]);
  }   
}   
printf("%s\n", input);
```

Comment: Short of what I'm sure you have your reasons for doing (only changing every *other* alphabetic char), is there a specific problem you're having? Did you want the *whole* string upper-case? If so, maybe lose the `alpha_count` logic.

Comment: The initializer in `char input[] = buffer;` is dubious.  Have you got the socket open already?  Are you by any chance trying to modify a string literal and crashing?  Also, it is aconventional to leave a space between the array name and the index square brackets: use `input[i]` not `input [i]`.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is in this section:

```
if (isalpha(input[i])) {
  if (alpha_count++ % 2 == 0 ) 
    input [i] = toupper(input[i]);
}
```

You need to use `islower` and think about the purpose of `if (alpha_count++ % 2 == 0 )` carefully. Here's what I'd use:

```
#include <ctype.h>

void str_upper(char *str) {
    do {
        *str = toupper((unsigned char) *str);
    } while (*str++);
}
```

Comment: Checking for `islower()` is not required. `toupper()` is defined by the standard to return the same character passed as the input value if there is no suitable upper-case conversion.

Comment: @WhozCraig Indeed. Thanks. I don't know where my mind is, at the moment :/

Comment: Man, I know that feeling all-too-well.

Comment: @WhozCraig I'm sorry to hear that. When emotions start to mess with my SO performance, I find mind-numbing activities such as retail therapy can be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

you have to modify this `for` loop

```
for (int i = 0, x = strlen(input); i < x; i++) {
  if (isalpha(input[i])) {
    if (alpha_count++ % 2 == 0 ) 
      input [i] = toupper(input[i]);
  }   
}
```

with the following code

```
for (int i = 0, x = strlen(input); i < x; i++) {
      input [i] = toupper(input[i]);
}
```

From the [toupper()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/toupper/) page of cplusplus.com :

> **int toupper ( int c );**
>
> Convert lowercase letter to uppercase Converts c to its uppercase
>   equivalent if c is a lowercase letter and has an uppercase equivalent.
>   If no such conversion is possible, the value returned is c unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

why not use _strupr?

```
_strupr(input);
```

Comment: Because it isn't part of the standard library. `strupr()` is part of POSIX and `_strupr()` is part of ISO C++.

Comment: Are you sure about `strupr()` being POSIX?  It isn't known to [POSIX 2008](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/toc.htm).  With the leading `_` prefix, it looks like a Microfaustian function.